# How do I encrypt passwords with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, encryption, password-encryption

I have some problems with encoding passwords,how can I do it. Type of encoding md5

```
digest(data text, type text) returns bytea;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION md(bytea) returns text AS $$
    SELECT encode(digest($1, 'sha1'), 'md5')
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STRICT IMMUTABLE;

INSERT INTO "login"(login, password, employee_id)
VALUES ( 'email',crypt('password', md('md5')), 1);
```

*** *Error* *****

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "digest"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1
```

Comment: The first character on the first line is where the error is. You have rubbish above your "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION"

Comment: I tried how you said but I have error .

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`digest(data text, type text) returns bytea;` is not valid syntax.

I recommend using `bcrypt` instead. No additional function definitions are required:

```
INSERT into "login" (login, password, employee_id) 
     VALUES ('email',crypt('password', gen_salt('bf'));
```

Later...

```
UPDATE table SET password = crypt('password',gen_salt('bf'))
```

And checking the password:

```
SELECT ... FROM table 
    WHERE password is NOT NULL 
      AND password = crypt('password-to-test',password);
```

Bcrypt is recommended by [Crafted Software](http://crafted-software.blogspot.com/2011/05/modern-way-to-store-passwords-bcrypt.html) and [Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html). The [official pgcrypto docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/pgcrypto.html) may also be of interest.

Comment: How can I desencrypt from my node server those passwords if I had encrypted previously my password column in the table?

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is old but for those who having the same issue.

**Step 1:** first check whether prcrypto is installed or not

```
select e.extname, n.nspname from pg_catalog.pg_extension e left join pg_catalog.pg_namespace n on n.oid = e.extnamespace;
```

**Step 2:** If it is not installed then create extension

`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto;`

**Step 3:** Computes a binary hash of the given data.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sha1(bytea) returns text AS $$
      SELECT encode(digest($1, 'sha1'), 'hex')
    $$ LANGUAGE SQL STRICT IMMUTABLE;
```

**Last Step:**

Also use encode function If you want the digest as a hexadecimal string

`SELECT encode(digest('blue', 'sha1'), 'hex');`

or

directly `sha('blue')`

Comment: Your method does not use salt. It means that for the same password - the result would be the same, which is a weakness. See the answer by @mark-stosberg for a more secure approach.