# ERROR: function crypt(character varying, character varying) does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

For a small project I am setting up a dummy-website (which currently only runs local on my notebook) with the use of JSP and JDBC. It is mainly meant to get in touch with the above mentioned technologies as well as HTML and CSS.

I am now at the point that I want users to be able to login to the website. I tested it successfully before with a password that was not encrypted in the database. For obvious security reasons I want to encrypt the password in the database, using the 'pgcrypto' extension for PostgreSQL.

I set everything up via pgAdmin and tested all the SQL successfully there. The inserted user is just for testing purposes, I wont use this user later.

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto

CREATE TABLE s68.USERS(
userid  SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
username    VARCHAR (150) NOT NULL ,
password    VARCHAR NOT NULL,
usergrp     VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT chk_usergrp CHECK(usergrp IN('admin','trainer','news'))
);

INSERT INTO s68.users(username,password,usergrp)
VALUES      ('admin',crypt('admin', gen_salt('bf')),'admin');
```

Unfortunately, when I try to run the SQL via JDBC so I can login, I get the following SQLException:

> ```
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function crypt(character varying, character varying) does not exist
>   Hinweis: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
>   Position: 63
>   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2422)
>   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2167)
>   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:306)
>   at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
>   at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
>   at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:155)
>   at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:118)
>   at beans.LoginBean.checkUseridPasswordSicher(LoginBean.java:50)
>   at beans.LoginBean.checkUseridPassword(LoginBean.java:26)
>   at org.apache.jsp.jsp.LoginAppl_jsp._jspService(LoginAppl_jsp.java:170)
>   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:444)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
>   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:407)
>   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> ```

Here is my code of the function which checks if the username and password are correct:

```
public boolean checkUseridPassword() throws NoConnectionException, SQLException{

        String sql = "SELECT username from users "
                    + "where username = ? and password = crypt(?, password)";
        System.out.println(sql);
        Connection dbConn = new PostgreSQLAccess().getConnection();
        PreparedStatement prep = dbConn.prepareStatement(sql);
        prep.setString(1, this.getUsername());
        prep.setString(2, this.getPassword());
        ResultSet dbRes = prep.executeQuery();
        return dbRes.next();    
    }
```

I am using the same database, users and schemas in pgAdmin as I do in JDBC.

Comment: Your `password` is defined as `varchar` not `text`. Try `crypt(?, password::text)` But why are you using the encrypted password value as the salt? Shouldn't that be in fact: `crypt(?, gen_salt('bf'))`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried this, but I am getting the same error, just that it does now say the function does not exist for (character varying, text).

I also changed the prepared Statement to be text, but then I also get does not exist for (text, text)

The solution for checking I got from here, i just changed it a bit, but the code works fine with pgAdmin, but neither does with JDBC
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656528/how-do-i-encrypt-passwords-with-postgresql

Comment: Are you maybe connecting to a different databases from within your Java code and pgAdmin?

Comment: I am connecting to the same database and schema. On another page of that website I am succesfully reading from the database. I use the same JDBCaccess.

Answer (score 1):

Though the original question is near two years ago, I've faced the same problem.

My solution was to make an explicit "public" schema on pgcrypto functions.
 With pgAdmin I connected with no explicit schema, and everything worked fine, But with JDBC, I connected with a different default schema, and coludn't see crypto functions.

In my case, I set public schema and cast parameters (fron character varying to text), which solved the problem: `public.crypt(text(*text_to_encrypt*),text(*salt_text*) )`

This worked for me, when JDBC connection is set to "s86" as default schema:

```
public boolean checkUseridPassword() throws NoConnectionException, SQLException{

    String sql = "SELECT username from users "
                + "where username = ? and password = public.crypt(text(?), text(password) )";
    System.out.println(sql);
    Connection dbConn = new PostgreSQLAccess().getConnection();
    PreparedStatement prep = dbConn.prepareStatement(sql);
    prep.setString(1, this.getUsername());
    prep.setString(2, this.getPassword());
    ResultSet dbRes = prep.executeQuery();
    return dbRes.next();    
}
```

Comment: You should improve this answer.